# Parse Data Migration DueDate

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Parse is shutting down soon and having a deadline for Database Migration 28th April 2016.

Currently I still have 2 production apps that is live on parse.com, but due to some tight schedule, I am afraid that I won't able to complete my parse database migration on time. Is there any way that can keep my app traffic prioritize even after the due date 28th April 2016?

I can't find any contact to Parse Support Team, that's why I'm asking the question here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Migrating-an-Existing-Parse-App

28th April 2016 is the RECOMMENDED date for migrating to self hosted MongoDB.

Comment: But if you look carefully there is a condition here stated in "What happens if I don't migrate my data by April 28, 2016?", and that seems like scared me a lot due to my current production apps with around 1m users.

Answer (score 1):

Just migrate the database. You don't need to migrate everything now. You have more time to do it. I will explain you supposing you will migrate to https://www.back4app.com

After the migration, both parse.com dashboard, back4app.com dashboard, https://api.parse.com and https://parseapi.back4app.com will be connecting to the same recent migrated database in back4app servers. It means that parse.com api and dashboard will keep working and the same data will also be available both in parse.com and back4app.com.

Therefore until the date you publish the new app connecting to parseapi.back4app.com, all your current customers will keep connecting to api.parse.com that will connect to the migrated database in the back4app servers. Everything will be working fine.

Then you have to test and prepare all your app and once you are comfortable you publish the new version of your app. When published, your clients will start updating their apps. The updated ones will be connecting to back4app.com and others to parse.com. But everything will be working fine because it is the same database.

The scenario described above will work until Feb 2017 and that's why it is important to start the migration process and then the publishing of the new app as soon as possible. So your clients will have more time to update their apps.